# separate one row into multiple based on value in row

Tags: r, split, rows

I am take a data frame similar to this:

| GISBLong | GISBLat | B Flyway | B Month | Count of Birds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -85.41667 | 42.41667 | 3 | 6 | 3 |
| -97.25000 | 36.0833 | 2 | 7 | 2 |

And change it into this:

| GISBLong | GISBLat | B Flyway | B Month | Bird ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -85.41667 | 42.41667 | 3 | 6 | 1.1 |
| -85.41667 | 42.41667 | 3 | 6 | 1.2 |
| -85.41667 | 42.41667 | 3 | 6 | 1.3 |
| -97.25000 | 36.0833 | 2 | 7 | 2.1 |
| -97.25000 | 36.0833 | 2 | 7 | 2.2 |

So split the rows by the number in the "Count of Birds". Currently 1 row represents multiple birds and I would like to have 1 row for each bird. Any thoughts or suggestions on a function to use? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`. Let `df` be your data.frame.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  uncount(Count_of_Birds) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Bird_ID = paste0(id, ".", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-id)
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  GISBLong GISBLat B_Flyway B_Month Bird_ID
     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  
1    -85.4    42.4        3       6 1.1    
2    -85.4    42.4        3       6 1.2    
3    -85.4    42.4        3       6 1.3    
4    -97.2    36.1        2       7 2.1    
5    -97.2    36.1        2       7 2.2
```

### Data

```r
df <- readr::read_table2("GISBLong  GISBLat     B_Flyway    B_Month     Count_of_Birds
                         -85.41667  42.41667    3   6   3
                         -97.25000  36.0833     2   7   2")
```